# using ajax for displaying MySQL data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

hi i'm new with php and i really don't know ajax. i making a photo gallery site i used the code below to display my photos i need to make possible with ajax or any other language, when someone click on the photo in index.php with the title example:"happy day 2012" want the photo being displayed in another page example:"photo/happy-day-2012"

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("test", $link);
$query = "select * from post order by id DESC;";
$results = mysql_query($query, $link) or die ("error!".mysql_error());
if($results){
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
echo $row['title']. "<img src=/1/" . $row['location']."width=580px>"."<br/><br/><br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Please if possible can use lot of comments  on the code.

Comment: What you need isn't AJAX, but mod_rewrite.

Comment: Do you have "shift" key on your keyboard?  Do you know how to split a chunk of text into sentences?  If you want others to help you, at least make it easier to read your question.

Comment: You can't run before you can walk. What you want to do is kind of a leap from where you are skill wise (based on your code sample). You're basically asking us to write this for you, not help with a problem you are having getting something to work. Do some php tutorials, maybe take a course or two at lynda.com and teach yourself some more fundamentals before attacking something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According a previous comment, you don't need AJAX, what you actually need is mod_rewrite. 
mod_rewrite is a Apache Module, that let's you rewrite urls according some pattern or rule.
To do this, it's common to use .htaccess file (that should be located on your site root). If you are in a development machine, make sure you've enabled AllowOverride on your Apache config file.

After that you can easily do something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule    ^photo/(.+)$ viewer.php?photo=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a very rough example, but basically what it does is... detects when a URI starts with "photo/" and send everything after that to another URL ($1 reference to what is found).

Later, you can determine on **viewer.php** what you want to show using **$_GET['photo']** variable.

But again, this is pretty advanced if you are new with PHP.